# Not able to set Banner add at bottom of screen, content remains at back of add

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, banner

alignParentBottom should do the trick, But my problem is that add is displayed at bottom of screen but other content are behind add. I want that add and content should not be overlapping. Pasting my layout file here-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="#c0b1b1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tv_header"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="Search for Quotes"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="srch"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/srchs"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="collapse"
            android:background="@drawable/uparrow"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#825465"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:minHeight="25dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_below="@id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is scrshot of problem, Note content behind the add not exactly above it.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYfs0.png)

Comment: With this code you'll of course going to get the result. What are you trying to achieve ? The question doesn't explains well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell your RecyclerView to always be above the adview.
Add the following line to your recycler view:

```
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view"
```